# javascript no transport error in asp.net service call using ajax

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

when we call a service using jquery ajax with predefined java script version jquery 1.4.1.min.js it is working fine..

but when we change the jquery to latest version like 1.7.1.min.js,or 1.8.2.min.js it shows in the internet explorer no transport error.

can any one help me with this. I tried the details mentioned in stack overflow but i does't[image]